# (Java) Not sure of the term, but basically how do I get the "opposite" of a number in a range?

Tags: java, math, equation

What I mean is, let's say that I have number between 0 - 400. If I were to pass in 0, it would return 400, if I were to pass in 1 it would return 399, and so on and so forth. Is there an equation that will let me do this? (Yes, I know this isn't really java as much as it is plain Math)

EDIT: WOW, I'm and idiot. How did I NOT realize that this was subtraction? My problem is with Slick2D, and I'm having difficulty working with the LWJGL origin (0, 0 being in the top left) v.s. the other origin (0, 0 being in the bottom left)

EDIT 2: Requesting for a moderator to delete this

Comment: if x is the number you pass in, `400 - x` will do the job

Comment: Who clicked "this question shows research effort"?  I mean, really?

Comment: @Josh you should be able to delete your own question

Comment: @trutheality No I can't because it has answers.

Answer (score 6):

It's called *subtraction*.

You take the highest number, call it `N`. Take the lower limit, call it `M`. Then you take the original number, call it `i`. Then

answer = (N  - i) + M;

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the difference.

`f(n) = 400 - n`

In Java, this might look like:

```
int getOpposite(int n) {
    return 400 - n;
}
```

For even numbers, passing in `n/2` will return `n/2` -- so in the case of `400`, passing in `200` will just return `200`.

Answer (score 1):

n = ULimit - n ; will give you the opposite